# Where can I see if I have ranked a weapon before to 30?

Tags: ps4, warframe

When ranking weapons for the Mastery Rank only the first run counts. If I wanted to sell already 30 ranked weapons, is there a way to see on a weapon if I ranked it before? I am pretty sure soon I will forget which weapons I already ranked up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just lookup the weapon in your **Codex**:

[image: Codes Screenshot]

The bars below weapons (Archwings, Warframes and Sentinels as well) will show you your progress.

If you've mastered a weapon before - even after selling it - it will keep that status and will still show that progress in your codex.